# Distributed load testing jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

What is the best way to manage multiple slaves(for eg:50 slaves) and run a load test?

When using distributed testing for jmeter, we need to manually handle all the agent start and stop, copy the files into each slave etc. Any suggestions to automate these type of activities. Is there any open source framework to handle all these?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your slaves live there could be different approaches:

1. Use "infrastructure as code" solutions like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to provision machines, install Java runtime and start JMeter slave process
2. If you have machines already but look for an automated way of configuring them you can use orchestration engine like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)
3. You can go for containers and container management systems like [Kubernetes @ Openshift](https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes)
4. You can go for [JMeter EC2 shell scripts collection](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2)
5. And finally you can consider cloud-based solutions which offer "JMeter as a service" like [LoadRunner Cloud](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-cloud/overview) or [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-JMeter-in-Distributed-Mode)

> Distributed mode for JMeter is enabled with simple option distributed under execution settings, listing JMeter servers under it:

> ```
> execution:
> ```
>
> - distributed:
>
>   - host1.mynet.com
>   - host2.mynet.com
>   - host3.mynet.com